# OBDII graphical car diagnostics

Tags: dual-boot

I am new to the Ubuntu environment installed 64bit Xenial on an AMD laptop and eventually managed to have everything working as the machine was restricted to OSs. Promised myself not to return to windows. I just had delivered to me an OBDII pc device but there is no software to support it in Linux and you can use it of course and I intend to do so but I'm afraid I don't meet the requirements at the moment. So I tried virtual box but no matter what I don't have USB and shared folders on the guest machine. Thought of making it a dual boot machine but it is a single hard drive split in three partition during the OS installation. Tried to partition it using gparted but I think I need to unmount the /dev/sda2 first. That might be possible using a live linux medium. I am concerned about potential data loss start up times and I also think that if windows partitions need to be at the start of the drive,so far left in gparted where my boot efi partition is. Ideally I want to install windows 7 32bit and I am not sure if that's possible considering my current OS is 64bit. I am aware that dual boot when Linux is the primary OS messes up the bootloader but I read it is fixable using linux live installation media. Please get back to me with suggestions on how to go about it.

Comment: I am confused by your question. It sounds like you would prefer a solution to use your OBD in Ubuntu (so good answer from mchid there) and are only trying to set up dual-boot as Plan C. There are many questions about how to set up VMs and how to dual-boot. I suggest you edit & simplify your question to make it more clear what you want to do.

Comment: Spot on, plan C is being kind, I need however to check whether the interface I got is working asap hopefully mchid's suggestion will do the trick and I won't have to resort to that. I don't imagine existing software either for windows or Linux giving you full access to the ECU which is what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

note: you will need to enable the universe repository

Ubuntu has at least two OBD scan tool software packages available.  You may be able to use one of these instead of the proprietary versions for your scanner.

Open a terminal and execute the following commands to install the software:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scantool obdgpslogger
```

To run the software, just search for scantool or run the following command in a terminal:

```
scantool &
```

I found this software using the following command to search:

```
apt-cache search obd
```

---

**I found some more info and will post more later as I find out more info.**

Run the following command to use the obdgpslogger GUI:

```
obdgui &
```

More helpful info:

```
man obdgpslogger
```

---

I took a look at the video and I see there are some differences between his terminal commands and the ones you would need to run.

First, unplug the device from your computer and run the following command:

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

This will list a whole bunch of stuff that does not matter.

Next, plug the device into your computer and then run the following command:

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

Now, you should see the same stuff listed and also the device should be listed as well.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try asap, in the meantime I installed OBD auto doctor the only software I found running in Ubuntu which is proprietary and doesn't work. While I was waiting for the PC diagnostics interface to arrive I watched a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkdRdKbMhPI

Comment: Thanks will give it a try asap, in the meantime I installed OBD auto doctor the only software I found running in Ubuntu which is proprietary and doesn't work. While I was waiting for the PC diagnostics interface to arrive I watched a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkdRdKbMhPI  where the uploader goes through on how to go about it using only the terminal, which is way out of my league currently but is what I am interested in, tried but couldn't set it up. Will let you know how it went with scantool.

Comment: ok seems like I need some help to set up the COM port. Tried scantool with all available COM settings and baud rates through the software but never actually connected please help me out with the settings.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1335098  do I also need a link as is suggested in the post? ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com1 where I replace .wine with .scantool?

Comment: @Nikos99 Sorry for the late response. I haven't tried it as I do not have an OBDII scanner to use with the software. As far as the other post is concerned, the other post is about using wine and so I do not think the other post will provide any helpful information for running scantool because all wine programs interact with hardware quite differently than they normally do and most of the time have no USB capability. Because scantool is a normal linux application I do not think the suggestion will help. I will check to see if I can find some more info on the subject.

Comment: @Nikos99 Also, don't let the terminal intimidate you if you aren't familiar with it. I think you may find it is much easier to do things that way many times. Tutorials for the terminal are much better when they are not on video though. I will take a look at the video you provided the link for.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the time you took to help me resolve the issue. From what I understand either I am using obd auto doctor, or scantool, or obdgpslogger, all in Linux, I need to set the COM port and I am clueless about it. This must be the reason they all fail. As I value your time and appreciate your good will trying to help me without having the device. Can we please arrange a time when we will both be logged on the forum to simplify things for both of us. Please let me know of your availability.

Comment: @Nikos99 I really don't know a whole lot about COM ports and stuff. You'd probably be better off asking a question about this either here or on http://unix.stackexchange.com Although, you should be able to see the device given the commands I have provided. I think I have a chatroom setup named mchid. I believe it is open and you should be able to tag my name with an @ symbol at the beginning of any comment so that I will get a notification for it. I should be on here off and on throughout the weekend as I have nothing better to do. If anything, we can try to move this conversation to chat.

Comment: @Nikos99 I think your com port should be something like /dev/ttyUSB0.

Comment: Please check at https://youtu.be/WgR9Zr4RITM the latest problems obdautodoctor is giving me, at https://youtu.be/ZYf-oWzdEf4 the problems scantool gives me. The ignition is not only on, the engine is running and a screencast sums up my problems thoroughly

Comment: if you're online having nothing better to do please instruct me on how to log on to your chatroom

Comment: ok I found your chatroom but my reputation is only 6

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you check out AutoCommander (https://autocommander.io). It's a suite of tools for hacking your vehicle, monitoring, control, and OBD diagnostics.  It's a Linux based package available for running on various Distros, and can even keep running in vehicle (eg: on a Raspberry Pi) if you want to build on its API.

It's totally free, and will run on a native Linux (if dual booted) or in a Linux VM if you go that route.